# Is there a simple way to temporarily disable the physics bodies for a sprite in Swift? (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, maze

I'm making a maze app, that generates a new maze after one is completed. Obviously, I can turn the walls (each having their own physics and sprite stored in their spot on an array) invisible by doing what I did in my code `wall[location].isHidden = true` ,but I couldn't find a way to do the same with the physics body bound to the wall, creating an invisible wall. Is there a simple way to do that without setting it to nil?

Just to clarify, it's not that I don't want it to be dynamic, I just want the entire thing to not exist while that maze is being solved.
Also the only reason I wouldn't want to set it to nil is because I don't know how to restore its old physics body in an easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way would be to physically remove your wall from your node tree.  This will increase performance since the system does not have to check unnecessary nodes.

Just make sure that your wall is being retained when you remove it so that you can readd it when needed.

```
wall[location].removeFromParent()
```

...

```
scene.addChild(wall[location])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, sadly I've already completed the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Sure

just set

```
isDynamic = false
wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
```

This pretty much isolates the SKPhysicsBody from the rest of the system. Do you have any SKJoints connected to your nodes with the bodies ? This can be awkward if you do.

or you can set it to nil

```
wall.physicsBody? = nil
```

then just make a method to set it again when your ready

```
 func addPhysics() {
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 5)
    wall.isDynamic = true
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = whatever
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = whatever
    wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = whatever
  }
```

If you do set to nil and then restore it make sure you do this at either the start or the end of the gameLoop.

In either of these override methods in the gameScene

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}

override func didFinishUpdate() {

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing the "nil" option that I found elsewhere because resetting the physics to my walls would be really hard due to how I did it. I'm going to try the other method and mark this as the "answer" if it works.

Comment: After trying your method, it didn't work sadly. Just FYI didn't mess w/ collision at all, just have my player cube run into the wall and not move.

Comment: After finding no other methods, I used the "nil" one you described and it worked, just was a lot of extra code.

Comment: Out of interest, why is it not enough to simply disable collisions and contacts for the physicsBody?

Comment: I'd guess he was resizing the wall texture and when he was finished the physics body no longer matched the shape. ? no idea really just a guess

Comment: `wall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false`,`wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0`, `wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0` should be how your wall is setup in the first place.  I am assuming these are walls that do not move.     What you need to do is set the `wall.categoryBitMask = 0`, since the issue is player's physicsBody is doing all of the physics work, and you do not want the player to compare with that wall.

Comment: No it shouldn't end of!! show me where it says that in any document it doesn't because its not. period. Sure remove the node is best but the OP never mentioned this was an option

Comment: The number of nodes in your scene can also affect performance if you enumerate all of your nodes within the update life cycle. While the SKView should...Nodes property can prune offscreen nodes out of an issued draw call, S...Kit must still enumerate all nodes in your scene to figure out which ones are offscreen, and this is an expensive operation. As a result, eliminating offscreen nodes yourself by using removeFromParent() is the fastest way to cull nonvisible nodes. Once a node is removed from the node tree, S...Kit no longer needs to consider whether it's onscreen or offscreen every frame.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/nodes_for_scene_building/maximizing_node_drawing_performance

Comment: wall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false,wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0, wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0 should be how your wall is setup in the first place -> no its not. period !!! The OP may of very well being doing something that he required the sprite to still be present in the  scene for

Comment: I do not understand the beginning part... I am assuming you are claiming I am wrong.  If an object does not move, then you should not be setting `collisionBitMask` or `contactTestBitMask`.  It becomes a wasteful check because it is an immovable object. The player is the one moving, so he needs to check if he hit a wall.  The only thing you need to change is `categoryBitMask` on the wall to 0.  This tells the physics world that nothing can contact or collide with it.  In a simple game, this is fine.  In a more complex game, you would need to use a more complex algorithm, or multiple flags.

Comment: No I'm not claiming you are wrong in your answer, your answer is correct an supported by the OP, but he never gave that removing the node from the scene was an option. Your statement about the SKBody n start up is not correct though. and thats enough from me. KOD you've helped me loads in the past so peace

Comment: My statement is correct, and is how you get the most performance out of your game.  If the OP thought that removing the node was an option, we would not be here answering his question LOL.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer, but another approach might be to subclass SKSpriteNode with one extra property called `inactivePhysicsBody` (or similar) which is an 'SKPhysicsBody'.

When you want to 'turn off' the physics for that node, set the `inactivePhysicsBody` property to `physicsBody` and then set `physicsBody` to `nil`. You can then easily restore the physics body when necessary.

Or you could add methods to the new class to do the same:

```
wall.activatePhysicsBody()
wall.inactPhysicsBody()
```

Comment: Hmm - this won't work, will it, as the PB will still exist; it just won't be connected to the wall. You could expand on the methods in the subclass to maybe 'move' the inactive PB to a safe location or disable collisions and contacts.

Comment: Depends on when you remove it.  As long as it is not during the physics phase, this should work.  Bodies are relative to the node, so without a node, a body would not be on the scene.

Comment: Also, no subclass needed.  Use an extension + userData

Answer (score 0):

Give the object that owns the sprite an 'extra' reference to the sprite's physics body, e.g.:

```
init(sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    self.sprite = sprite
    self.physicsBody = sprite.physicsBody
    super.init()
}
```

Then you can set `self.sprite.physicsBody` to either `self.physicsBody` or `nil` to turn the object's physics on / off. Personally I'd avoid subclassing here but YMMV.